# How to create a FTP user with specific /dir/ access only on a Centos / linux installation

Tags: centos, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

So I'm on a VPS - CentOS  Linux installation. I have vsFTPd on the server.
I currently have SFTP access to the server via my root user, but am now trying to create a new user with FTP access to a specific directory only on the server, I've done the following:

```
1. mkdir /var/www/mydomain.com
2. mkdir /var/www/mydomain.com/html
3. useradd <-username>
4. passwd <-username>
5. chown –R <-username> /var/www/mydomain.com
5. groupadd <-groupname>
6. gpasswd -a <-username> <-groupname>
7. chgrp -R <-groupname> /var/www/mydomain.com
8. chmod -R g+rw /var/www/mydomain.com
```

**What I'm struggling to do is to create the user to ONLY have access to** `/var/www/mydomain.com` - I observed that the user correctly logs into the right folder, however the user can then browse "back" to other directories. **I want the user to stick in the specific folder and not being able to "browse" back**.

Any ideas?

I've found different articles on chrooting, but simply haven't figured it out to use it in the steps included above.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-centos-7 You can follow this to solve your issue

Comment: for those who are on Ubuntu 18 here is the version specific https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's quite simple.

You have to add the following option on the vsftpd.conf file

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

The documentation inside the configuration file is self-explanatory:

```
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
```

This means, that the user will just have access on the folder you configured as HOME of the user.Below, i have an example of a user passwd entry:

```
upload_ftp:x:1001:1001::/var/www/sites/:/bin/bash
```

Set the home directory of the user with the following command

```
usermod -d /var/www/my.domain.example/ exampleuser
```

**Note:** In my example, this user is also a valid user for some scheduled tasks inside Linux. If you don't have this need, please change the shell of the user to `/sbin/nologin` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Hi nwildner! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer me on this.

So in my vsftpd.conf file ive added the following line "chroot_local_user=YES" - then as I understand it I need to add a line similar to the one you show for my user?

Must admit im not entirely sure what to write there with the example you provide. the "1001" etc what is that? Lets assume my user is called: "im_a_linux_noob" and the directory for that user is: "/var/www/mydomain.com" - how would that look like?

Comment: And would I be able to do this without any additional steps of what ive done in my post? So doing 1-8 and then adding what you describe should do the trick?

Comment: Hi. The example above is just a line(modified, of course) of the `/etc/passwd` file, that represents a user called upload_ftp, 1001:1001 is his User Id and Group ID, /var/www/sites is the home directory of the user(and the parameter that vsftpd reads from) and /bin/bash, the shell.  Probably what is missing on your case is a home directory to the user, and it could be solved with the following command: `usermod -d /var/www/mydomain.com <username>`. Cheers :)

Comment: Ahh makes sence then.

So just to be sure - that line from the passwd file, is not anything to put in the vsftpd.conf file, correct? Only chroot_local_user=YES is needed in the vsftpd.conf file...? Eitherways tried both scenarios - still same output for me :/

Comment: Also ended all of my steps with the usermod line you provided. I login in the wished folder, however I can still browse back too all other folders on the server. After uploading the vsftpd.conf file and adding the user, I also restarted httpd. Any ideas ?

Comment: ISSUE SOLVED! I shouldnt restart httpd, however do: /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart

Comment: Yup thanks a lot. One issue though. It works fine loggin in through normal FTP , however when I login as SFTP - then I can browse back again - any ideas?

Comment: Certainly because sftp is being handled by your ssh server, not by your ftp server. In a "crude" way: SFTP = SSH + FTP; FTPS = FTP + SSL. There is a thread about sftp here, and i'll quote it to aviod subject duplication ok? ;)   http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64541/34720

Answer (score 7):

After you've changed your config to include `chroot_local_user=YES`

You could change the user's shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin` so that if the password leaks you will have mitigated some risk (set the home directory too). The shell needs to be listed in `/etc/shells` as well or authentication will fail.

> usermod -d /var/www/my.domain.example  -s /usr/sbin/nologin  exampleuser
>
> -d, --home HOME_DIR
>             The user’s new login directory. If the -m option is given the contents of the current home directory will be moved to the new home directory, which is created if it does
>             not already exist.
>
> -s, --shell SHELL
>             The name of the user’s new login shell. Setting this field to blank causes the system to select the default login shell.

https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/FAQ.txt

Answer (score 5):

Here are steps to setup a user and allow the user access only via FTP (i.e. no SSH) and also limit access to a specific (user home) directory on **proftpd**:

1. Add new user: `adduser newusername`
2. Set password: `passwd newusername`
3. Modify user home directory from default to a new folder:

   `usermod -d /target/directory username`
4. Edit `shells` file: `vi /etc/shells` and add `/dev/null` at the end
5. Modify `newusername` entry in the `passwd` file: `vi /etc/passwd` to add `/./` before the `newusername` so that the entry looks like this:

   `newusername:x:502:502::/home/ftp/./newusernamehomedirectory/:/dev/null`

   [Details for steps 4 & 5 here:](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap29sec295.html)
6. Edit `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` file and uncomment the line `DefaultRoot ~`

Comment: It may be safer to use a utility like `vipw` when editing `/etc/passwd`. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433227/6424

Answer (score -4):

Run this command:

```
useradd -d ftp_user:chown 711 /etc/init.d/
```

Comment: You should consider expanding your post to have, at least, some helpful explanation or documentation.

Comment: This is an awful answer. You're essentially giving the ftp user full access to the /etc/init.d/ directory - complete madness. 

711 explained - http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/0711/

Answer (score -6):

Set the root folder permissions to **711** with your root account.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that??