# adding FTP user without changing owner of directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, aws

Sorry, but this is probably a terribly stupid question.
I'm running a Linux2 instance on AWS.
I have a number of sites running there, including a couple of wordpress sites.

One of the sites wants an FTP account so they can edit their wordpress files directly.

I want to create an FTP account and lock it to the site directory.

i've read a number of interesting answers here and on other sites (eg [How to create a FTP user with specific /dir/ access only on a Centos / linux installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83221/how-to-create-a-ftp-user-with-specific-dir-access-only-on-a-centos-linux-ins))

it looks like every answer says after adding a new user you :

```
chown –R <-username> /var/www/mydomain.com
```

my question is, is this changing the ownership of this directory? is this something i need to do? will this affect the permissions and access of other users?

Sorry for the probably silly question, still fairly new to Unix and don't want mess up a live website.

Comment: Create a group with the new user and the owner of the directory? https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **groups** : https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2017/12/how-manage-users-groups-linux . It basically allows you to set the rights of several users over files and directories.

More info : https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-groups-command/
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups