# SFTP/SCP only and chroot

Tags: ssh, scp, sftp

We have a SFTP Server and a bunch of users.
The users share files over the SFTP Server with us (not the best solution, I know).

Every user is chrooted into a different directory to prevent them from cd to a higher directory and seeing the other users (Folders are named after users).
another requirement is, that only SCP(/SFTP) is allowed - so no shell.
We also want certificates for authentication.

Until now we used scponly to meet all the requirements.
But scponly is deprecated now so we can't use it anymore and need an alternative.
Some Googling brought SFTP chroot and rssh to daylight but neither seem to meet all specifications.

EDIT: We are using SLES 12

Comment: Does this [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/591781/creating-sftp-users-and-jailing-to-chroot-on-centos-user-authentication-error) article help?

Comment: nice tip, but we need to block SSH Shell access.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64541

Comment: The part that sets their shell to `/bin/false` stops that for you. You could also consider the `no-pty` option in `authorized_keys`.