# Setting up vsftpd as a sftp server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd

I am trying to set up vsftpd (or another application) to serve as sftp service on an Ubuntu server. I would like to expose sftp for one (or a handfull) of system users, ideally they should have a chroot jail to location different from their home directory. This seems like something I should be able to handle with vsftpd, however I do not understand what is happening and suspect "some other service" is actually responding to my sftp requests. This is what I have done:

1. apt install vsftpd and configure to the best of my knowledge.
2. I can sftp in to the server and put and get files, however the chroot does not work.
3. I *remove* vsftpd with `apt purge vsftpd`
4. I can *still* connect to the server with sftp and put and get files?

So - to it seems that the first problem I need to understand/solve is who is actually replying to my sftp requests - as it does not seem to be the vsftpd installation?

This is a stock Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Comment: Is `openssh-server` installed? That would provide sftp by default. AFAIK `vsftpd` provides an *FTPS* service. See also [How to configure SFTP so it behaves like ftp chrooting user to his home directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64523/how-to-configure-sftp-so-it-behaves-like-ftp-chrooting-user-to-his-home-director)

Comment: Yes - `openssh-server` is installed; so that is probably my secret helper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[SFTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13)** is, in fact, the **SSH File Transfer Protocol** aka **Secure File Transfer Protocol**. It is a SSH application and it has nothing to do with [FTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959) (and therefore with `vsftpd`). As you correctly said, it is provided by the package `openssh-server`, service `sshd`.

You were probably looking for **[FTPS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4217)** (**FTP Secure** aka **FTP-SSL**) which is an extension to FTP and, as such, is can be provided by `vsftpd` and other FTP servers; it uses TLS to make FTP secure.

To further complicate things, there was once a **[SFTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc913)** (**Simple File Transfer Protocol**), an insecure, simplified version of FTP which never became a standard and has now historical status only. A simplified, lightweight, no-login FTP that is in use nowadays is **[TFTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1350)** (**Trivial File Transfer Protocol**).

You can use either SFTP or FTPS to replace the insecure, plaintext FTP. I'd say that SFTP is probably more standard and robust.

Answer (score 1):

OK - as pointed out by @steeldriver my main confusion came from the fact that I was using the sftp service of openssh and not the vsftpd software I had installed.